# I'm having trouble inserting a Mongodb record with geospatial data in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm trying to insert a record that contains a nested array of geospatial data. I've even tried making the array an object instead, but no luck there either. Here's more or less the insert line:

```
$collection->insert($obj, array('safe'=>true));
```

One interesting thing is that when I call the index 'loc' something else, such as just an integer, the insert works.

Here's the array that should be going into Mongodb, but isn't:

```
Array
(
  [name] => Home
  [address] => 500 Pole Line Road
  [city] => Davis
  [state] => CA
  [zip] => 95618
  [loc] => Array
    (
      [lon] => -121.726710
      [lat] => 38.549576
    )

)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No error messages, but something strange I've found is that the insert works when I change the array index from 'loc' to 'location' or something else. Will that mess up the geospatial indexing?

Comment: I don't think it should, I have seen examples of keys other than loc.  You will have to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't care about the keys for a geospational "field". It just takes the first two elements with the first one being longitude, and the second lattitude. Even if you'd name your first one "lat" it would still be seen as the longitude. The only reason why I could think it would not insert is perhaps you have a unique key on some fields.

If you'd add a full working (but small) example of what you're inserting, then I can update the answer to hopefully show what is wrong.

Comment: Okay the issue is totally embarrassing, but what was happening is that I was doing an API call to get lat/long, and those numbers ended up being strings that I was trying to insert via the 'loc' array. The thing that I don't totally understand yet, is why a string was not permissible. Obviously a it wouldn't be usable by the geospatial index unless mongo was smart enough to convert the data type, but something was restricting the entire insert from working. I guess it was either the PHP driver or mongo, but somebody didn't like those strings! It was easily fixed by typecasting to double.

Answer (score 0):

```
array( 'loc' => array( floatval($lon),  floatval($lat)))
```